# How to add <div> and <p> tag as prefix and suffix in CDATA detail section using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

**Tools:**
I am using XSLT and XML.

**Detail Description and Problem:**

I have an XML and there is node called "detail", below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<news type="detail">
    <article id="694141" published="7/20/2011 1:19:52 PM" language="English">
        <title><![CDATA[myData &amp; Arik Air sign interline agreement]]></title>
        <detail><![CDATA[<strong>Gives passengers greater access to cities across Nigeria and West Africa&nbsp;
            <br /></strong>&nbsp;DUBAI, U.A.E., 13th July 2011: myData (<a target="_new" href="http://www.myData.com/">www.myData.com</a>), one of the world’s fastest growing airlines, has signed an interline agreement with leading Nigerian carrier Arik Air, making it easy for customers to access a wide range of points across Nigeria and West Africa.
            <br />
            &nbsp;
            <br />
            Under the new agreement, customers will be able to purchase joint myData-Arik Air itineraries, enabling them to connect seamlessly from myData’ double daily services to Lagos onto cities including Abuja, Kano, Kaduna, Port Harcort and Enugu .
            <br />
            ]]>
        </detail>
    </article>
</news>
```

In above XML node "details", you can see the there is CDATA used, now above content in the "detail" section is copy and pasted by editors, sometime they put `<div>` and `<p>` tag in the begining of "detail" section and sometime they missed to put `<div>` and `<p>` tag while copy and paste process and this makes whole formatting problem to my page, so now I want to check whether if there is `<div>` and `<p>` in the begining of the section then it should behave as normal else we will add `<div>` `<p>` as prefix and `</p>` `</div>` as suffix. To get this I am using below logic in XSLT, however not getting success to do it.

I have got an XSLT and below is the few code taken from it.

```
<xsl:variable name="art_detail" select="/news/article/detail" /> //here I am taking all the node object in variable

<!-- Check if the immediate preceding sibling was a p or div tag? Yes - Use the same XML, No - Add a <div> tag to the xml result --> 
<xsl:variable name="addNode2Detail">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(starts-with($art_detail,'&lt;div&gt;')) or (starts-with($art_detail,'&lt;p&gt;'))">
    <xsl:value-of select="$art_detail"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;div&gt;',$art_detail,'&lt;/div&gt;')"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="detail" select="utils:DecodeCDATA($addNode2Detail)" />
```

The Above Logic is working fine, however I don't want to use "starts-with" instead of this I would like use something like

```
<xsl:when test="($art_detail//preceding-sibling::div or $art_detail//preceding-sibling::p) and node() and string-length(normalize-space(//text())>1)">
```

Below is the sample code which I am trying to write, but not getting any success "msxsl:node-set" is again giving problem and its remove all the formatting section, I mean page looks wiered.

```
<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="($art_detail//preceding-sibling::div or $art_detail//preceding-sibling::p) and node() and string-length(normalize-space(//text())>1)">
        $<xsl:apply-templates select="$art_detail" mode="content"/>$
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>            
         *<xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set(concat('&lt;div&gt;',$art_detail,'&lt;/div&gt;'))" mode="content"/>*
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Please suggest any other logic to achieve above solution!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use things like preceding-sibling::div because there is no div element in your document. The whole point of CDATA is to say "the stuff in here is character data; it may look like markup, but I don't want it treated as markup". So whoever decided to wrap the content in CDATA was deliberately trying to stop you doing this.